# equation of a line 30 units perpendicular to the corresponding points of another.

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

I am looking for a method, preferably using calculus or trig, to calculate a function which is $30$ units perpendicular away from the corresponding point in the other function. As in, for function $f(x)$, every point in $g(x)$ is $-30$ units away perpendicular to the corresponding point in $f(x)$. I am looking for a formula or method to solve for $g(x)$ for all $f(x)$ where f(x) is a exponent and a sin curve

One of the equations I have attempted to do this with is $$f(x)=25 \sin((40^{-1})*x) + 50$$ but have so far been unsuccessful.[diagram of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sAaWw.png)

Answer (score 1):

Let $f'(x)$ be the derivative of $f$, assuming $f \in C^{1}(\mathbb{R})$ (this should not be a problem). Notice that every point of $f'(x)$ is the slope of the tangent line of $f$.

Now remember that two lines $y_1 = m_1x + b_1$  and $y_2 = m_2x + b_2$ are perpendicular iff $m_1 \cdot m_2 = -1$, thus the function

$$g(x) = \frac{-1}{f'(x)}$$

Assuming $f'(x) \neq 0$ is the function of the slope of the line perpendicular to every point $x$ of $f$.

I think from here you can solve it quick.

Comment: that is a useful method for two linear lines, but i dont see how it would work for a sin curve. I tried modelling the equation you showed me, and it has not really worked.

Comment: If you do the math you obtain $g(x) = f(x) - 30$. Prove it using the method I said, this is, find the C constant for the line $y = \frac{-x}{f'(x)} + C$ that contains the point $(x,f(x))$, replace it in the equation and see what happens. I guess you got the excercise as homework or something so I didn't want to put the answer directly...